# Complex Analysis book reference - Gamelin or Stein-Shakarchi?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I've finished studying **real analysis** (from *Tao* and *baby-Rudin*). Now what I want is a rigorous, comprehensive yet enjoyable to read (i.e. not dry) book on **complex analysis** with good-quality exercises. Now I'm confused between *Gamelin*'s book and *Stein-Shakarchi*'s book. I know both of the books are great but I want to start with only one book (for time-constraints). Can anyone tell me the distinct features of these two books and which one should I pick to set out?

[I know that there are a lot of reference requests for books on *complex analysis*, but my query is more specific about the two books mentioned. So I decided to ask it as a separate question. I hope it doesn't come under the duplication-policy.]

Comment: Pick Stein-Shakarchi. Gamelin's book is an example of a mathematical book which is the opposite of a rigorous book.

Comment: @Artem: Thanks!